# Store dynamic allocated 2D array with different column size

Tags: c++, arrays, cin

```
int n;
cin >> n;

char** matrix = new char*[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> (matrix[i] = new char);
}
```

but as i input 
3
45523
36
578

it encounters break point and the program stops

but if i input
3
45523
368
578

it works fine
not sure why is this happening

Comment: Are you intending on reading strings? use `std::string` and put them in a `std::vector`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: How are you intending to store the size of these arrays so that you can verify you don't overstep the array bounds later when you are using the data? If you make each of these a `std::vector` the `.size()` member function will let you see that later. Otherwise you'll have to store the size of each array allocated. Also for allocation, it should be `= new char[number of characters];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert in C++ (and make no mistake, if your code needs a C++ compiler then it's purely a C++ question), but I suspect what's happening is that you're allocating one `char` per field, and overflowing that one-byte buffer. Perhaps things would be different if you allocated eight bytes per field, instead, like so: `cin >> (matrix[i] = new char[8]);`... Better yet, it'd be wisest and most C++ish to use `std::vector<char>` (however, you'll still need to reserve eight bytes for the fields in your examples) or `std::string`.